# Can not correct to display data from ms sql tables in datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

No idea how to fix that.
So i have an imported table (screenshot) **Patient** (# 1) and **Diagnoz** (Diagnosis) (# 2) from the MS SQL Server. The first table contains a complete list of patient data and a foreign key for the id_diagnoz in which the Stage and Name_diagnoz is indicated. 
Table (# 3) is a ready-made option for outputting data without unnecessary columns, but this is not a problem.`"select Pacient.id_patient, Pacient.Name, Pacient.Surname, Pacient.Middle_name, Pacient.Age, Pacient.Legal_address_Clinic, Diagnoz.Name_diagnoz, Diagnoz.Stage FROM Pacient JOIN Diagnoz ON Diagnoz.id_diagnoz = Pacient.id_diagnoz";` That's work well.

---

*The problem is* that when filling in the data from the textboxes and comboboxes, I need to first generate an id_diagnoz from the table (# 2) and with it add the other info to the patient table (# 1). However, I could not manage to do this for several hours, because even the error did not lead. Therefore, I decided to separately add the id_diagnoz to the empty table (# 4) to make sure that my query is working.
Please, help me with this id_diagnoz and other data put into the patient table.

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-R551818\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Fond;Integrated Security=True"))
            {



                SqlDataAdapter comm = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT id_diagnoz FROM Diagnoz WHERE Name_diagnoz = '" + comboBox2.Text + "' and Stage = '" + comboBox3.Text + "'" +
                    "INSERT INTO Pacient (Name, Surname, Middle_name, Column__Passport, Legal_address_Clinic, Age)" +
                    " VALUES (@Name, @Surname, @Middle, @Passport, @AddresClinic, @Age) ", conn);

                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox3.Text);
                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", textBox4.Text);
                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Middle", textBox5.Text);
                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passport", maskedTextBox1.Text);
                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AddresClinic", comboBox1.Text);
                comm.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", textBox7.Text);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                comm.Fill(ds);
                //da.Fill(ds, "Pacient");

                dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                conn.Close();

                conn.Open();

            }}
```

[Screenshot for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTc9J.png)

Comment: You should share with us the error you get, but a quick check makes me see that you're missing a space before your `INSERT` keyword in your query: `" INSERT INTO Pacient`.

Comment: You should parameterize ALL your predicates. You ruined your sql injection protection when you munged your textbox values into the middle of your string like that. You should also avoid using AddWithValue as it sometimes gets datatypes wrong. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ And last but not least give your controls a name that tells you what it is. TextBox1 is useless. When you have 20 textboxes on the screen and you need to get LastName you have to look at the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you specify id_diagnoz in your insert query and supply the value of that field with the subquery you had there?
Something like:

```
INSERT INTO Pacient (Name, id_diagnoz, Surname, Middle_name, Column__Passport, Legal_address_Clinic, Age)
VALUES (@Name, 
SELECT id_diagnoz FROM Diagnoz WHERE Name_diagnoz = '" + comboBox2.Text + "' and Stage = '" + comboBox3.Text + "'",
@Surname, @Middle, @Passport, @AddresClinic, @Age)
```

Comment: You should not provide such dangerous code as an answer. This is perpetuating the bad habit of concatenating strings which allows for sql injection.

Comment: @SeanLange Just trying to address the question that was asked. You're absolutely right that the way the query is constructed is problematic also. Did not want to cause confusion further. One problem at a time.

Comment: Thanks everyone :)